# Zyxel P-660HN-T1A modem limits only wireless connection to only 8 devices

Tags: wireless-networking

I have a Zyxel P-660HN-T1A modem, which connects to my ISP.

I have an 8-port ethernet switch connected to it and other laptops connect via Wireless.

As soon as upto 7 laptops connect to the modem, the Zyxel doesn't let any other device connect.

If I try from my phone [HTC HD7, works fine otherwise], I get the error: `Could not reach network!`

I am at a loss, what is the issue and how do I resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

My ISP's zyxel had a 5 DHCP lease limit (non-expiring leases). We never have more than 5 devices around at any moment, but many visitors each day, so we had to reboot it every morning to allow new machines to connect. I reconfigured the zyxel to 50 DHCP leases max. No problems after that (I google for my ISP's password).

Answer (score 0):

It could be a hard limitation of the firmware. Your best bet is:

1) Call your ISP and bite their head off

or

2) Turn the routing on your modem off, and get a proper router behind it.

Comment: Will applying some other firmware onto it work?
Will try (1) as well.
And getting a proper router will cost me, which I am trying to avoid. :P

Comment: @manishkungwani you will probably be hard pressed to find 3rd party firmware for such an obscure device. Getting a proper router for yourself may initially be more than you're willing to part with, but you can see benefits from it. Such as getting an actual gigabit switch built-in (this games a big difference over 10/100). It also is yuor property, so if you switch ISP's then you keep it. You also get full control over the device.

Answer (score 0):

Change the pool size to a higher one (highest value is 254).